# SQL Server rowversion/timestamp and indexes

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Some `RowVersion` column in a table has been incremented and I don't know why. The result is that every client get outdated data. So I'm looking for the cause of this unwanted incrementation.

Does a rebuild / reorganize of indexes in SQL Server increment a `RowVersion` (`timestamp`) column of that table?

Additional question : a `RowVersion` is unique within a table; but is it also unique in a database, in a server? I'm pretty sure it's unique in a database.

Comment: RowVersion is used for version control. When you update a touple the rowversion also changes. This is used by applications to ensure they are not overwriting data with stale data. Think of 2 apps that want to update the same row using the same initial data but at different times. That is why it exists and how it was meant to be used. You should not rely on the values being auto incremented or try to use these values for other logic other than this.

Comment: `rowversion` is *meant* to be incremented by any modification, to allow optimistic concurrency. It's not usable for ordering or indexing. Its value has no significance outside its row. Clients shouldn't depend on it to get changes

Comment: Why do you use `rowversion`? If it is to detect changes, the appropriate mechanism is [Change Tracking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/about-change-tracking-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017). It's very lightweight and available in all SQL Server versions and editions. Change tracking can detect deletions too

Comment: Rebuilding or reorganizing of indexes does not increment a RowVersion. It only gets updated when you making update of data in your table. For more details - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/rowversion-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: @VladyslavYefremov that link warns that duplicates *are* possible in some cases.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, thanks never knew and didn't pay attention to it

Comment: @VladyslavYefremov I too tried to use rowversion as a change detection mechanism and quickly found out that it can't be used that way. I discovered change tracking after that which doesn't require any changes to the tables themselves

Comment: Thx guys. **Rebuilding or reorganizing of indexes does not increment a RowVersion** ok.
Why I'm using `rowversion` : a client start with `version = 0`, it retrieves its "not terminated" data (EndDate is null) ordering by RowVersion desc and it keeps the last RowVersion (let's declare it ClientRowVersion), then each minute every client ask for its data where RowVersion > ClientRowVersion, if data exists then ClientRowVersion = result.First().RowVersion etc...
Do you think I could use Change Tracking for a Table with EF6 in a similar way ?

Comment: By the way, I think I found my problem. Every night I archive some data from DB to another db called Archives, I just notice that the RowVersion **is incremented too** in Archives (the value is far different so we can say that a RowVersion is unique per database). Also the data are inserted in a "random order" so RowVersion order is not kept. Sometimes, I have to repatriate some data to DB from Archives. I just notice that data are also inserted in a "random order" and **RowVersion is incremented again !** so it explain why the client retrieve outdated data !

Answer (score 1):

- Rebuilding or reorganizing of indexes does not increment a RowVersion
- RowVersion is unique per database